# Laravel flutter login

Tags: php, laravel, flutter

I am trying to connect my website to my flutter app. I made the website using laravel framework and now I have a problem logging in from my app because laravel utilizes bcrypt algorithm for hashing. How can I log in through accounts created from laravel through my app? Right now login works when hashing is done through md5 but it only works on the app and not the web. I tried using bcrypt as mentioned below but it didn't work.

```
$email = $_POST['email'];

$password = md5($_POST['password']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password = '$password'";
```

tried using:

```
$password=password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to deal with this yourself you would retrieve the user by email or username. Then if you have a record you get the hashed password from that and verify it against the plain text password.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=:email";

// do what you have to execute the prepared statement and get a record

if ($user && password_verify($_POST['password'], $user->password)) {
    // have a record and the password was verified
}
```

Comment: Thing is, the api I have created is just to connect to mysql database. It isn't in any way linked to laravel and thus rendering it impossible to use any of the functions of laravel. I was searching if there were some way that I can match two independent hashing for authentication. since md5 hashing always generates same hash value it was successful but bcrypt generates different for same password each time. I found my problem. The only way to solve it seems is to create api in laravel or to change hashing to md5 in laravel. I'll go with later for now. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: there is nothing laravel related about this, this is just PHP ... you don't need to do the comparison in the database ... retrieve the record then verify the hash .. the hash will be different every time it is generated which is why there are special methods to verify the hash .. i could send you a hash and source and you could verify it as well, its not system specific

Comment: dont change to md5 .. any system can verify the bcrypt hash, there is no reason to change away from bcrypt

Comment: So I wrote hash verification code in php, and when I copied hash from mysql and checked, it worked. But for some reason, my code still doesn't work for app. Code: `$email = $_POST['email'];
   $password = $_POST['password'];
         
   $hash="SELECT password FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
   if(password_verify('$password',$hash)){
   $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
   $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
   }`
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nevermind. I fetched rows of the corresponding email and verified after that. 
`password_verify($password, row['password'])`
I was actually going to change to md5 which also turned out to be quite troublesome. Regardless, everything is working in order right now. Thank you for your kind suggestion. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You should be posting the password from the app to the site and doing the hash checks from the backend like so

```
$user = User::where('email', $request->get('email'))->first();

if ($user && Hash::check($request->get('password'), $user->password)) {
    // User exists and password matches.
}
```

EDIT:
If you are having issues with Hash::check give auth attempt a go.

```
if (Auth:attempt($request->only('email', 'password')) {
    // User exists and password matches.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response and great suggestion. But the problem here is that I am writing the API on core php (not a lot of context available on the internet) and I have encountered issues with the Hash::check returning false on numerous occassions. Does it work on core php?

Comment: Actually, I am not connected to the website whatsoever through the app. I am just sharing same mysql database for both device for which I built website through laravel and app through flutter. I am using http requests to connect my app to the database. Therefore, I seem to have issue regarding using laravel functions as I am performing http requests through core php.

Comment: you would use `password_verify` then

Comment: I used password_verify and managed to get it to work. Everything is working now. Thank you for your kind suggestions. Cheers.